# Conditional characteristic functions and distributions

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

> Let $X$ be an RV, $\mathcal{F}$ a $\sigma$-algebra, $\phi$ the characteristic function of a  distribution $\nu$. Assume that for the conditional characteristic function
>
> $$\phi_\mathcal{F}(t) := \mathbb{E}[\exp(itX) \mid \mathcal{F}]$$
>
> holds $$\phi_\mathcal{F}(t) = \phi(t) \quad a.s. \qquad (2)$$
>
> and show that $X$ has distribution $\nu$.

I know that two RVs have the same distribution iff they have the same characteristic function, but I do not see how to use it here. Could you please give me a hint?

Edit: Following Stratis Markou's suggestion I took the conditional expectation of $(2)$:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\phi_\mathcal{F}(t) \mid \mathcal{F}] &= \mathbb{E}[\phi(t) \mid \mathcal{F}] \\
\Longleftrightarrow  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(itX) \vert \mathcal{F}] \mid \mathcal{F}] &= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(itX)] \mid \mathcal{F}] \\
\end{align*}

In class we have done the tower law/law of total expectation, but when I us this here I only get $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(itX) \mid \mathcal{F}]] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(itX)]]$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: $\phi(t)=E[\phi(t)]=E[\phi_\mathscr{F}(t)]=E[E[e^{itX}|\mathscr{F}]]=E[e^{itX}]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it help if you took expectations w.r.t. to the conditioning variable on both sides of the second equation and then applied the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)?

P.S. I'm a little unsure of what you mean by having a $\sigma$-algebra in the conditioning side in your first equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to use you suggestion, but I did not succeed in using the tower law; see my edit.

Comment: See [@Snoop](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/915356/snoop)'s comment to your question above :)